# When the argument of complex numbers is a well defined real valued function?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, multivalued-functions

I know that the argument $\arg:\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}\to\Bbb R$ is multivalued function and also that if we consider $\arg:\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}\to{\Bbb R}/{2\pi \Bbb Z}$, then it is a well defined function. I am having trouble in understanding

1. when the argument of non-zero complex numbers can be treated as a well defined real valued function and when it will  be continuous as a real valued function,

2.If we define $\arg:\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}\to{\Bbb R}/{2\pi \Bbb Z}$, is the argument a continuous function ?

Help is appreciated.

Comment: 2) If you put the right topology (or metric, if you like) on $\Bbb R/2\pi \Bbb Z$, then yes.

Comment: meaning the subspace topology of the complex plane on $\Bbb R/{2\pi\Bbb Z}\simeq\Bbb S^1$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Actualy I am interested in viewing $\arg$ as a real valued function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is continuous as a map $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}\to \mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}\simeq S^1$. In polar coordinates, it can be identified with the projection $(0,\infty)\times S^1\to S^1$ onto the second coordinate.

But as a function to $\mathbb{R}$, it can only be made continuous if you restrict the domain to $\mathbb{C}\setminus H$ where $H\supseteq \{0\}$ is some set such that each loop in $\mathbb{C}\setminus H$ is contractible in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$.

This is not an if and only if statement, it is just necessary (if $\mathbb{C}\setminus H$ contained a loop incontractible in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, then this loop has a nonzero winding number $n$ and the argument would rise by $2\pi n$ when going around this loop). Sufficient is, for example, if $\mathbb{C}\setminus H$ is an open connected and simply connected subset of $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: what is halfline? how to prove the second part?

Comment: A halfline is something homeomorphic to $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Where do I find the proof that it is continuous on  $\Bbb C \setminus H$ if $(\Bbb C \setminus \{0\})\setminus H$ is simply connected?

Comment: In this generality, it follows, for example, from Hatcher, Algebraic Topology, Proposition 1.33. But this is an overkill -- it should be simple to see it. You can define it by choosing the argument at one fixed $x$ arbitrary and then define $arg\,\,y$ by means of a curve that connects $x$ and $y$: the result is independent on the curve, if the space is simply connected.

Comment: Still don't get it. I will try to prove it. Otherwise I'll get back to you. Anyway thanks for the reference.

Comment: You are welcome. I should add, however, that $\mathbb{C}\setminus H$ shouldn't be too wild. It doesn't work if it is the set of all rational nonzero complex numbers (which is simply connected), for example. Definitely "open in $\mathbb{C}$ and connected and simply connected" is sufficient but don't ask me for an "if and only if" statement at this hour.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is multivalued if taking the first definition, and well-defined (i.e. single-valued) if taking the second.
2. Since $\mathbb R/2\pi\mathbb Z$ is isomorphic to $S^1$, it is indeed a continuous function. However if you choose a single representative for each equivalence class (such as $\mathbb R\to [0,2\pi)$), the resulting function is necessary noncontinuous.